# Stream data into Google earth, view the time-tagged in real-time, and play it back using time slider (Update Security Violation)

Tags: google-earth

After a lot of trial-and-error my current approach involves manually loading a kml file into Google Earth. This file contains 2 NetworkLinks to 2 webservers on the same machine as Google Earth.

The web servers are created in Java using *undertow*, which provides a basic HTTP handler, and the ports used are `8081` and `8082`.

The first NetWorkLink HTTP handler (at port 8082) creates a kml file with  Document with `id=-1`. The second NetWorkLink HTTP handler (at port 8081) creates a kml file with a NetworkLinkControl containing an Update to a Document with `targetId=-1` with many Creates for various Placemarks, each with a time-tag.

My intention was that the second NetWorkLink would add these time-tagged Placemarks to the previously created document by the first NetworkLink. The problem I am seeing is the Google Earth error:

> Error while parsing file http://localhost:8081 at line 2 column 0
>   Update Security Violation

When I search on this error I see references to the use of Update for local files used in NetworkLInks, but I am using `http:localhost`, and not a local file.  Does anyone know what is causing this Google Earth error message?

Comment: Does either KML include a NetworkLinkControl and/or Update element? Also have you tried using the explicit IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.101) in the href ?

Comment: Yes, the output of the second HTTP handler's KML data includes NetworkLinkControl and Update with many Creates within them to hopefully add time-tagged data to the original NetworkLink KML.  I tried 127.0.0.101 just now, but the same error occurred (Update Security Violoation).

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a Google Earth local access violation issue.

In Tools/Options menu click on the General tab and check "Allow access for local files and personal data" option. [image: Google Earth Options]

Comment: That option was already checked in my version.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Today I tried running the 2 servers on a different machine than the one that Google Earth was running on.  I received the same error "Security Violation."  I am going to try to add the 3 KML files, the original one that is manually loaded which contains 2 networkLinks, and 2 files of data returned by the 2 web servers specified in the 2 networkLinks.

Comment: The first file seemed to be too large to fit in a comment.  I am a beginner at StackOverflow, so it is probably just my ignorance. @JasonM1

Comment: here is answer to post files as attachments  - use third party website (e.g. dropbox) and post the link -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I didn't post anything, because I received some help here and at  http://www.gearthblog.com/contact  .  I think my problem was that I was using 2 web servers for the 2 network links, and the URLs I used in my KML contained the port numbers in them.  So my new approach is to use one undertow web server with 2 URLs, each with its own handler as shown below.

Comment: private void initServer(int serverPortNumber) {
        webServer = Undertow
            .builder()
            .addHttpListener(serverPortNumber, HOST_NAME)
            .setHandler(Handlers.path()
                .addPrefixPath("/autsens/networkLink1", new NetworkLink1Handler()) 
                .addPrefixPath("/autsens/networkLink2", new NetworkLink2Handler()) 
            ).build();
        webServer.start();
      }